# Cannot use theme attributes in a drawable. Got android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException error

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-drawable

I got the following shape drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#222222" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="58dp"
        android:topRightRadius="58dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="58dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="58dp">
    </corners>
    <padding
        android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp" />
</shape>
```

I am setting color attribute from my theme in this line:

```
<stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Project compiles alright without any issues, but during runtime on a device I got the following problem:

```
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #119: Error inflating class TextView
    ...
    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
 res/drawable/bordered_green_solid_textview.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07006a
```

When I replace **?attr/colorPrimary** and use for example hex color like **#222222** it will run without any problem.

What should I do to use **?attrs** in my drawables without problems?

**P.S.:** My min API level 19

**My TextView**:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/imagesCounter"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bordered_green_solid_textview"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="16"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="9sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageBorder"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageBorder"
            tools:text="67" />
```

Comment: can you post code of textview

Comment: where have you defined your colorPrimary?

Comment: Added textview xml to post

Comment: I defined colorPrimary in my theme as follows:  <style name="DesignAppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/designColorPrimary</item> ...

Comment: Theme attributes can't be used in XML drawables prior to Lollipop. You'll have to put your drawables that have theme attributes in `drawable-v21/` folders, and use workarounds for older versions; e.g., separate drawables for each theme, setting the colors manually at runtime, etc.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I know these tricks, but i thought that it might be possible to do it more clearly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I found out that for API level like 19 the only possible way is to make separate drawables for different themes of your application.

So first of all you need to declare you new attributes for drawables in **values/attrs.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...
    <attr name="nav_bar_header_drawable" format="reference"/>
     ...
</resources>
```

Then in your theme you should set drawable for this attr and now you can reference it anywhere you want.

```
<style name="Theme.MyDarkMaterialDesign" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
        ...
        <item name="nav_bar_header_drawable">@drawable/side_nav_bar</item>
       ...
    </style>
```

It works perfectly for API 19 and may be below (didnt test since I only need 19 API and above).

Answer (score 0):

is better way to use color from your color value or use a hex color.
if you have to use ?attr value :

1. you should define color
2. create file res/value/attrs.xml
3. define color in a style and set value for your attr
4. use your attr in drawble

Comment: I did this. Problem is that I got an exception. Seems like for my api level i have to restor to tricks described by Mike . M. in a comment above

Answer (score 0):

Why must you use the ?attr

Just call

```
android:color="?colorPrimary"
```